# ConnectionError: Failed to connect to {database server} - Could not connect (sequence)

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database, cpanel, amazon-rds

I'm running this node.js application on a shared hosting site (cPanel) and run into this connection problem to the RDS SQL Server and I'm not sure what I can do to get more information on the problem so I can fix it or how to fix it.

I can successfully connect to the SQL Server using SMSS, furthermore, using the SAME node.js code I can connect to the SQL Server on my main desktop. This connection problem only occurs when running the same code on cPanel.

I have allowed all IP address access (All traffic inc TCP/UDP)through the RDS VPC security group: 0.0.0.0/0

I'm just confused as it works on my desktop but does not work on the hosting site, as the security group allows all access from all IP's. Is possible for the hosting site to prevent connections to databases and is something I should look into?

ERROR:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to  - Could not connect (sequence)
>
> Failed to connect to  - Could not connect (sequence)
>   code: 'ESOCKET'
>   name: 'ConnectionError'

Code used to connect to the database:

```
// config for your database
var config = {

    user: ...,
    password: ...,
    server: ..., 
    database: ...,
    port: 1521,
    dialect: "mssql",
    dialectOptions: {
        instanceName: "SQLEXPRESS"
    }

};

// connect to your database

sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

});`
```

Comment: Firewall issues or maybe the server running it can not see/access the SQL server.

Comment: I had a feeling it could be the server's (cPanel) problem. Unfortunately, I do not have permissions to use nc or telnet to see if it can see the SQL server. I guess this is more a question I will need to ask cPanel. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Brad was right, this is a cPanel specific problem.

As I'm using shared hosting on cPanel (through namecheap), connecting to a SQL SERVER or any remote database instance is not permitted for security reasons.

If anyone wishes to connect to a remote database using the same methods, ensure you do not have shared hosting. :(